# Is this a javascript method or property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having the hardest time getting my terminology right. In the following code:

```
Notes.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  newNoteName: null,

  actions: {
    createNewNote: function() {
        var content = this.get('content');
        var newNoteName = this.get('newNoteName');
        var unique = newNoteName != null && newNoteName.length > 1;

        content.forEach(function(note) { 
            if (newNoteName === note.get('name')) {
             unique = false; return;
           }
         });

        if (unique) {
            var newNote = this.store.createRecord('note'); 
            newNote.set('id', newNoteName);
            newNote.set('name', newNoteName);
            newNote.save(); 

            this.set('newNoteName', null);
          } else {
            alert('Note must have a unique name of at least 2 characters!');
         }
     } 
  }
});
```

What is 'newNoteName:', 'actions:', and 'createNewNote:'?

Are they methods or properties or hooks? What are the differences? And does 'createNewNote' being nested inside of 'actions:' make 'actions' something altogether different?

What is the difference between ember 'hooks' and methods/properties that you create and name yourself and how they're used?

Thank you.'

[UPDATE]

Where does 'content' come from?

```
Notes.NotesNoteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
    updateNote: function() {
        var content = this.get('content');
        console.log(content);
        if (content) {
            content.save();
        }
    }
 }
});
```

It isn't an attribute of the model so how does Ember know what to retrieve with

```
this.get('content')
```

Does it come with the `textArea` handlebars helper?

Comment: I rather see them as key/value pairs, same as in the JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the previous answers are correct, however, none of them address the Ember conventions at play in your question.

`newNoteName` is a property of the `NotesController`.  Inside the template called `'notes'` you can display it using `{{newNoteName}}` or use it in an input with `{{input value=newNoteName}}`.  In the `NotesController` you can read the value with `this.get('newNoteName')` and you can set the value with `this.set('newNoteName')`.

`actions` is a special property on Ember controllers.  Any functions declared in the `actions` hash can be called in a template.  Using `createNewNote` as an example, you can use something like this to call the function in response to a button click:

```
<button {{action 'createNewNote'}}>Create New Note</button>
```

`createNewNote` is a controller action.  It can be called from a template, as shown above, or it can be invoked from other controllers or views using `send`.

From another controller you might have this:

```
Notes.OtherController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs : ["notes"],
  actions : {
    someAction : function(){
      this.get('controllers.notes').send('createNewNote');
    }
  }
});
```

[UPDATE] : Addressing the question about hooks.

In Ember hooks are functions that you can create on your objects that Ember will call at various points as it manages your object hierarchy and lifecycle.  For instance, in a `Route` you will often want to implement the `model` hook.  If you have declared a function called `model` in a `Route`, then Ember will call that method automatically when it needs to get a hold of the model that is to be represented by that route.  This allows you to override the default way that Ember looks for a model, without needing to also implement all of the things that Ember does in the way of Route/Controller creation and setup.  Hook methods are really technically no different than other methods that you may implement on your objects, the only real difference is that Ember will automatically call hook methods at the appropriate time.

[UPDATE 2] : Where does `'content'` come from?

`content` is the object that your controller is representing.  The route sets the `content` on the controller, and it is retrieved from the `model` hook.  Ember has some smart defaults built in that will try to do the right thing based on your `Router`.  But you can implement the `model` hook to return whatever you want.

If you haven't created `Notes.NotesRoute` yourself, then Ember is generating one for you that is more or less equivalent to this:

```
Notes.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    return this.store.find('note');
  }
});
```

That controller is finding all `Note` models and setting that collection to the `content` property of the `NotesController`.

Comment: Thanks very much! This helps a lot. Do you know of any other sources that explain this in more detail?

Comment: The Ember guides is probably the best resource.  http://emberjs.com/guides/  I just realized that I missed your question about hooks.  I'm going to add an [UPDATE] to my answer.

Comment: One more question popped up regarding 'content'. I updated my question if you get a second. Thanks so much.

Comment: See [UPDATE 2] in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for this great and detailed answer. I'm *guessing* that the question may arise from reading the Ember.js In Action book which left me with the same question about the "content" line, which is repeatedly presented in code, but not explained at all. It's a shame that the book has not been written/updated to account for this, but good that resources like StackOverflow can pick up the slack.

Answer (score 2):

They are all properties of an object, they just have different types.

In your code snippet:

- `actions` points to another `Object`,
- `createNewNote` is a `Function` object (which, when assigned to a property, is referred to as a "method"), and
- `newNoteName` is just a reference to `null`, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a JS expert so hopefully my terminology will be at the right level...

Essentially all JS boils down to Functions and Objects.  Anywhere you see {..} you have an object, as this is called Object Literal Notation.

Objects have properties, whose values can be anything from null to other Objects (strings etc) to functions.

Functions take arguments, which can be other functions or objects.

So, extend and createNewNote are functions, and the argument passed into the extend function is an object, and the value of the action property is an object.

Comment: Functions are just `Function` objects. (Almost) everything in JavaScript is an object.

Answer (score 0):

"newNoteName" is a property.
"actions" is a property.
"createNewNote" is a method.

Suggest you take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

They are all properties or "names".

Thinking JSON helps understanding better what's happening.

Just consider you have an object. You can set properties of this object by giving them a name. You can assign to this property a value, which can be an object, a string, an array, a function, etc.

```
var myObject = { propertyName : propertyValue }
```

Answer (score 0):

`newNoteName` is a property, equal to `null`.

`actions` is a property, containing an literal object.

Inside that anonymous object, `createNewNote` is a method defined by an anonymous function.  It's not just a property set to a function, because that would evaluate to the result of the function.  To call this method, you would use this:

```
Notes.NotesController.actions.createNewNote();
```

This will execute the function set in createNewNote.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ember.js, so the function may get called in some other way.